Question about Neumann eigenvalues on manifolds
Question:
Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{S}^2_+$ be any geodesically convex subset of the hemisphere $\mathbb{S}^2_+$. Then is it true that $\mu_1(\Omega)\geq \mu_1(\mathbb{S}^2_+)$ where $\mu_1$ is the first (non-trivial) Neumann eigenvalue of the Laplacian?
The above statement clearly fails when $\mathbb{S}^2_{+}$ is replaced by a rectangle in the plane and $\Omega$ is a thin strip around the diagonal of the rectangle. Still, I am wondering if such a construction generalizes to the hemisphere as well.
Update: Surprisingly this problem seems harder than it looks.

So far the best estimates on $\mu_1(\Omega)$ that I found here:
$$\mu_1(\Omega)\geq \frac{\pi^2}{D^2} + \frac{1}{2}$$
where $D=\operatorname{diameter}(\Omega).$ Thus if $\mu_1(\Omega)<2$ then $D> \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3/2}}.$ This also gives a lower bound on the perimeter of $\Omega$ since $P(\Omega)\geq 2 D \geq \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}} \pi.$
On the other hand, it is also known that $\mu_1(\Omega)\leq \mu_1(B)$ where $B$ is a geodesic ball of the same volume as $\Omega.$


Here's a heuristic. Call the smallest Neumann eigenvalue the "zeroth" so we can just say "first." The first eignvalue for the hemisphere is no smaller than $2$ (as that's the first nontrivial Neumann eigenvalue of the sphere). A long narrow convex subset of diameter $L$ will look like a geodesic of length $L$, so its first eigenvalue is close to the first eigenvalue of the interval of length $L$, namely $\frac{\pi^2}{L^2}$. Since the longest possible diameter is $L=\pi$, the smallest first eigenvalue of a long narrow interval should be $1$ and $1 < 2$

@Neal that is what I had in mind, but I am having trouble showing that the eigenvalues of a thin tube around the half-geodesic converge to the eigenvalues on the half-geodesic with the flat metric as the thickness of the tube tends to zero.

Do you need to show convergence? Just estimate the first eigenvalue of the thin tube: Take tubular coordinates $(s, r, \theta)$ where $s$ is the long dimension and $r,\theta$ vary in the thin cross-section disk. Let $u(s, r, \theta) = \cos(\pi s / L)$. Maybe I'm wrong about the complexity of the computation, but I think one should be able to show $\int u = 0$ and get a good estimate its Rayleigh quotient from above.

(Also, I think convergence is delicate: the eigenfunctions that have radial variation across the tube will have their eigenvalues blow up, only the eigenfunctions that have minimal/no radial variation will have their eigenvalues converge.)

Let $\Omega$ be a connected domain and denote its the Neumann eigenvalues by $ 0 = \mu_0(\Omega) < \mu_1(\Omega) \leq \cdots $
Let $\mathbb{S}_+^2 = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{S}^2\ |\ y \geq 0\}$ be the hemisphere facing the positive $y$ direction. Because every Neumann eigenfunction on $H$ extends to an eigenfunction on $\mathbb{S}^2$ by reflection, $\mu_1(H) \geq 2 = \mu_1(\mathbb{S}^2)$.
We will formalize the intuition that a long, thin convex subset should have a low-frequency spectrum very similar to that of a line segment. We do this by defining a convex subset $\Omega\subset \mathbb{S}_+^2$ and a test function $u$ on $\Omega$, and estimate its Rayleigh quotient $R(u)$ to show
$$ \mu_1(\mathbb{S}_+^2) \geq 2 \geq R(u) \geq \mu_1(\Omega).$$
Define $\Omega$ as the image of
$$ [0,\pi]\times[-\epsilon,\epsilon] \ni (s,r)\to \left( \cos(s)\cos(r), \sin(s)\cos(r), \sin(r)\right) \in \mathbb{S}_+^2$$
This defines geodesic normal coordinates for a very thin strip around the equator $H\cap\mbox{$xy$-plane}$. The $s$ coordinate measures distance around the equator, and the $r$ coordinate measures distance away from the equator.
Figure that the first Neumann eigenfunction on the strip should be basically the same as on the line, so pick a test function $u(s,r) = \cos(s)$. Calculating in the $(s,r)$ coordinates, the $L^2$ norm of $u$ is $\pi\sin(\epsilon) $ and the $L^2$ norm of its gradient is
$$ \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \frac{dr}{\cos(r)}. $$
The integral factor is bounded by $2\epsilon \leq \int_{\epsilon}^\epsilon dr/\cos(r) \leq 2\epsilon/\cos(\epsilon)$
So the Rayleigh quotient of $u$ is estimated above and below by
$$ \frac{\epsilon}{\sin(\epsilon)} \leq R(u) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\cos(\epsilon)\sin(\epsilon)} $$
By choosing $\epsilon$ small enough, the upper bound is less than $2$. The function $u$ is mean-free, and $\mu_1(\Omega)$ minimizes the Rayleigh quotient over all mean-free functions. So the estimate on $R(u)$ shows that $\mu_1(\Omega) < \mu_1(\mathbb{S}_+^2)$.

Thank you for your answer, but I am not sure if the thin strip is a geodesically convex subset of the hemisphere, what do you think?

Good catch. I think this is fixed by considering a "banana" between two geodesics that intersect at the equator on the boundary of $\mathbb{S}^+$, andhave an angle of $2\epsilon$ between them. This domain's convex (a geodesic connecting two points must be the "long way round" since a shorter path along the bdry can be found), and the estimate is modified with inner integral limits dependent on $s$. I think since integrands are all positive, the upper bound will carry through. If I have time later this week I'll check this and update my answer more carefully. But lmk if you see a flaw here.

The first eigenvalue of this lune is $\frac{\pi}{2\epsilon}(\frac{\pi}{2\epsilon}+1)$ which blows up as $\epsilon\to 0,$ so I am not sure if this argument would work.

@Student you sure that's not the first Dirichlet eigenvalue?

that is also the first Dirichlet eigenvalue, see Section 2 here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10455-021-09797-y

but by repeating the ODE argument it seems that they should be the same, what do you think?

@Student after separating variables $u=R\Theta$, Neumann conditions mean that the latitudinal function $\Theta(\theta) = \cos(k\pi\theta/\beta)$ with $k=0,1,2...$. So the longitudinal function $R$ can be a Legendre function of order zero, as well as positive order.

that makes sense but the order of the Legendre function is now fractional so I am not sure how to work with it, but I think that in general, the eigenfunctions should be $\cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{\beta}\theta\right)P^{\frac{k \pi}{\beta}}_l(\cos(r))$ and $\lambda = l (l+1),$ do you agree?

the first eigenvalue of the lune is just 2 and strangely it is independent of the angle. It corresponds to the case when k=0 and l=1 above.

@Student I was thinking this is the case as well and am quite surprised.
